# need to strip out unwanted text

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to strip out all text before and including "(" and all text after and including ")" in this variable.

```
var this_href = $(this).attr('href');
```

The above code produces this...

```
javascript:change_option('SELECT___100E___7',21);
```

However it can produce any text of any length within the parenthesis.

A Regex solution is OK.

So in this case I want to end up with this.

```
'SELECT___100E___7',21
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than stripping out what you don't want you can match want you want to keep:

```
/\((.*?)\)/
```

Explanation:

```
\(    Match an opening parenthesis.
(     Start capturing group.
.*?   Match anything (non-greedy so that it finds the shortest match).
)     End capturing group.
\)    Match a closing parenthesis.
```

Use like this:

```
var result = s.match(/\((.*?)\)/)[1];
```

Comment: Ok, but how to put this into something usable? How do I take the old variable and make a new one or replace the value in the variable with the sliced value? Not sure what to do with this.